# Checking whole array over a multiple JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database

To filter a table output of selected entries from a single table i would need something like a multiple JOIN request through several tables.
I want to filter a table of people by a special column in the table. Lets say this column is "tasks." Now tasks is also another table with the column "people" and the values between those two tables are connected with an existant "join" table in the database, which is matching several IDs of one table to each ID of the other table.
Now if this would be simple as that i could just filter with an INNER JOIN and a special condition. The problem is, that the entries of the table "tasks" are connected to another table over a "join" table in the database. To simplify things lets say it is "settings". So each "task" consists of several "settings" which are connected via a join table in their IDs.

So what is the input?
I got an array of IDs, which are representing the settings-ids i do not want to be shown.

What should be the output?
As already said i want a filtered output of "people" while the filter is "settings."
I want the sql request to return each entry of the table "people" with only joined tasks that are not joining any of the "setting-ids" from the array.

I hope you can help me with that.

Thanks in advance!

**Example**

> Settings-Table:
>   1. Is in progress
>   2. Is important
>   3. Has unsolved issues
>
> Tasks-Table: (settings.tasks is the join table between many tasks to many settings)
>   1. Task from 01.01.2012 - JOINS Settings in 1 and 3 (In progress + unsolved issues)
>   2. Task from 02.01.2012 - JOINS Settings in 2 (Is important)
>   3. Task from 03.01.2012 - JOINS Settings in 1 and 2 (...)
>
> People-Table: (people.tasks is the join table between many people to many tasks)
>   1. Guy - JOINS Tasks in 1, 2, 3 (Has been assigned to all 3 tasks)
>   2. Dude - JOINS Tasks in 1 (Has been assigned to the Task from 01.01.2012)
>   3. Girl - JOINS Tasks in 2, 3 (...)
>
> Now there is an array passed to a sql query
>   [2,3] should return noone because every person is assigned in a task that was either important or had unsolved issues!
>   [3] would return me only the person "Girl" because it is the only one that is assigned to tasks (2 and 3) that had no unsolved issues.

I hope it is clear now. :)

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.  We need to see the structure of your tables with a few example data rows, then you need to show us what you want your result to look like.  Also, the less text in your question, the more people will read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT PEOPLE.* 
FROM PEOPLE INNER JOIN PEOPLE_TASKS ON PEOPLE.PERSON_ID = PEOPLE_TASKS.PERSON_ID
WHERE TASK_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT TASK_ID
                      FROM TASK_SETTINGS
                      WHERE SETTING_ID = <Id you don't want>)
```

EDIT (for supplying multiple setting ids you don't want)

```
SELECT DISTINCT PEOPLE.* 
FROM PEOPLE INNER JOIN PEOPLE_TASKS ON PEOPLE.PERSON_ID = PEOPLE_TASKS.PERSON_ID
WHERE TASK_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT TASK_ID
                      FROM TASK_SETTINGS
                      WHERE SETTING_ID IN (<Id you don't want>))
```

Comment: Wow thanks alot man :)
But does it also work if <Id you don't want> is an array?

Comment: @NikoM. what do you consider an array?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to `join table people` and `table tasks` with the `join table`, let's call it `people_tasks`.

```
select distinct p.* from people p
inner join people_tasks pt on p.people_id = pt.people_id
inner join tasks on t.tasks_id = pt.tasks_id
```

Then you have to `join table tasks` and `table settings` with the `join table`, let's call it `tasks_settings`. You have to `join` them in the current `select`.

```
select distinct p.* from people p
inner join people_tasks pt on p.people_id = pt.people_id
inner join tasks on t.tasks_id = pt.tasks_id
inner join tasks_settings ts on t.tasks_id = ts.tasks_id
inner join settings s on s.settings_id = ts.settings_id
```

and now you have all `people` connected with its `tasks` and its `settings`. Finally you need the `restriction`. With the people with the settings selected, you choose the others like this:

```
select distinct p.people_id from people p
inner join people_tasks pt on p.people_id = pt.people_id
where p.people_id not in (
    select distinct p2.people_id from people p2
    inner join people_tasks pt2 on p2.people_id = pt2.people_id
    inner join tasks t2 on t2.tasks_id = pt2.tasks_id
    inner join tasks_settings ts2 on t2.tasks_id = ts2.tasks_id
    inner join settings s2 on s2.settings_id = ts2.settings_id
    where s2.settings_id in (list of ids)
)
```

Comment: That won't work. If a person has a single task, and that task has 2 settings, one of which is the one the OP doesn't want, this query will return the other row for that task and therefore a row for the person.

Comment: If there is a `tasks_settings (task_id, setting_id)` table like this: `(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5)` and the array of settings supplied is `4, 5`, then your query would ‘allow’ tasks `1` and `2`. But the OP says: *‘…with only joined tasks **that are not joining any** of the "setting-ids" from the array’*. That is, `2` should be filtered out because it is associated with the unwanted setting `4`. So, I think, you should apply `NOT IN` (or an equivalent construct) at a different stage, not to the list of settings, but somewhere to the list of tasks.

Comment: @AndriyM now it won't have that problem.

Comment: @aF: Still don't think its quite right.. It'll now return all people irrespective of whether they have an associated task or not..

Comment: @StevieG haha you are correct :P now it has everything!! omg what a big query :$

Comment: @StevieG I've only join with `tasks` because I think it's what he asked it.